# Management Studio not found for SQL Server R2 2008 Developer Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Just installed the SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition all the features were installed but the Management Studio to manage your database queries etc was not installed :S

I have SQL Server 2005 with Management Studio installed but when I installed the 2008 R2 Developer Edition the Management Studio did not install or something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL SERVER 2008, Management Studio is not included in your setup. so it has not installed. Visit this site and get that. And also uninstall 2005 management studio or while installing it will upgrade.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: I think you can both installed at the same time

Comment: Don't download it, just install it from your original ISO. Choose the add new features and management studio is in the list, about half way down. The other thing is that you can use both concurrently if you wish. When connecting to a 2008 box, intellisense will only work in SSMS 2008 and when connecting to 2005, only SSMS 2005 will display intellisense - they didn't include 2005 intellisense in ssms 2008, go figure!